# Way to make equal-population areas of world using administrative divisions?

Tags: administrative-boundaries

I am trying to make a map, that aims to divide the world into areas each with an equal population. I've found things like Dave's Redistricting for individual US states, but nothing for the entire world. Mapchart has something similar, but nowhere near as detailed as it needs to be and no population data. Is there any way to use population estimates of second or third level administrative divisions for every country, and make equal areas of, say, 1,000,000 people per division? It doesn't have to be accurate.

Comment: What software are you using, or is it just a general concern?

Comment: Just in general, I’ll use whatever will work